# How to configure the chromedriver.exe in eclipse

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have downloaded chromedriver.exe and eclipse, 
I have added through add external jars 
but while executing it gives me error

> Error: Could not find or load main class demochrome.DemoChrome

```
package demochrome;


public class DemoChrome {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "E://chromedriver.exe");
        System.out.println("Welcome to chrome");

    }

}
```

Comment: How are u running this? eclipse? command line? check ur classpath?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "Could not find or load main class" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18093928/what-does-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-mean)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend page factory pattern, working example:

```
public class NewTest {
String baseUrl = "http://google.com"; 
String driverPath= "C:\\chromedriver.exe";

WebDriver driver;

@BeforeTest
public void beforeTest() {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", driverPath);
    driver  = new ChromeDriver();
```

}

and in @Test

```
driver.get(baseUrl);
```

Maybe you changed class name in code (in project there's another name) and you have improper slash in "E://chromedriver.exe"

Answer (score 0):

`E://chromedriver.exe` is not a valid path.  try `E:/chromedriver.exe` or `E:\\chromedriver.exe`